# What is this "rushed inwards" type of photo called?

Tags: digital, style, zoom-blur

I saw a photo on the internet today that I have seen before. Not this exact image, but this type of photo. I have tried to explain it to people in a photography store but to no avail.

What is this technique referred to, so that I can find more information related to it.

I love that "rushed inwards" stream around the focus in the centre of the image.

[image: rushed in photo]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zoom **Burst**, or Zoom **Blur** are a couple of variations of names of the effect you're talking about.
More info on how to achieve it [here](http://digital-photography-school.com/using-the-zoom-effect/), [here](http://digital-photography-school.com/how-it-was-done-zooming-exposure/), or [here](http://www.photographymad.com/pages/view/how-to-take-stunning-zoom-burst-photos).

Comment: Can you give a short summation of the technique instead of just linking off-site?  A quick example is what most people need to figure out how to use something like this in their own work.

Comment: I quite often would in answers; I didn't initially bother in this case, since the question was "what is this effect", not "how do I achieve it".

Answer (score 3):

I like the term **Radial Motion Blur** as it describes both the appearance of the effect and how to achieve it in post processing (most Photoshop editors have a "radial blur" function).

**Zoom Blur** does describe how to achieve the effect, though.